# Logstash Load Error - Java

Tags: java, java-8, logstash, jruby

I need help figuring out how to solve this error. I'm running elastic search 5.6.2 and log stash 5.6.1 (and tried 5.6.3 and 6.0.0) and JDK 1.8 but I'm getting an error when trying to run log stash.  This is on OSX 10.12.6

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseParNewGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper to method sun.nio.ch.SelChImpl.getFD()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
io/console on JRuby shells out to stty for most operations
LoadError: load error: jopenssl/load --     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /Users/perkinsl/logstash-5.6.1/vendor/jruby/lib/ruby/shared/openssl.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /Users/perkinsl/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/patches/stronger_openssl_defaults.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /Users/perkinsl/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/patches/stronger_openssl_defaults.rb:2
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /Users/perkinsl/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/patches.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /Users/perkinsl/logstash-5.6.1/logstash-core/lib/logstash/patches.rb:5
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
   (root) at /Users/perkinsl/logstash-5.6.1/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:70
```

I've tried running a config test but it doesn't get that far.

Comment: Some people got same problem and need  to complete reinstall java to environment. But it seems to be Java 7 and install Java 8 because their HOME was set so 7. Check if it really uses Java8 and maybe have a look [here - log stash issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/7770)

Comment: Thanks.  A complete uninstall/re-install of the JDK and setting Java_Home seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A complete uninstall/re-install of the JDK and setting Java_Home seems to have done the trick.